# When should there be a dot in JSDoc generics?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I see some people write JSDoc for JavaScript generics like this (with a dot):

```
/** @param {Array.<Bar>} bars the bars that should be fooed*/
function foo(bars) {}
```

and others like this (without the dot):

```
/** @param {Array<Bar>} bars the bars that should be fooed*/
function foo(bars) {}
```

Whats the point of the dot? Which version is correct? When should I use one and when shouldn't I?

Comment: Related, but not sure if this is up-to-date information: https://github.com/jsdoc/jsdoc/issues/1375

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a syntax point of view all these types expressions are valid when you run `jsdoc index.js`

```js
/** @param {Array} x */
const a = x => x;

/** @param {Array.<string>} x */
const b = x => x;

/** @param {Array<string>} x */
const c = x => x;

/** @param {string[]} x */
const d = x => x;
```

It should be noted that the Google Closure Compiler doesn't seem to recognise the `{<type>[]}` type expression e.g. if you compile this:

```js
/** @param {string[]} x */
const a = x => x;
```

You get the following warning:

```
JSC_TYPE_PARSE_ERROR: Bad type annotation. expected closing } See https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Annotating-JavaScript-for-the-Closure-Compiler for more information. at line 1 character 18
/** @param {string[]} x */
                  ^
JSC_TYPE_PARSE_ERROR: Bad type annotation. expecting a variable name in a @param tag. See https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Annotating-JavaScript-for-the-Closure-Compiler for more information. at line 1 character 18
/** @param {string[]} x */
                  ^
```

See this Google Closure Compiler [fiddle](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home#code%3D%252F%252F%2520%253D%253DClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540output_file_name%2520default.js%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540compilation_level%2520ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS%250A%252F%252F%2520%253D%253D%252FClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%250A%252F**%2520%2540param%2520%257Bstring%255B%255D%257D%2520x%2520*%252F%250Aconst%2520a%2520%253D%2520x%2520%253D%253E%2520x%253B%250A).

The static type checker in VS Code will complain about the last three function calls:

```js
// @ts-check

/** @param {Array} x */
const a = x => x;

/** @param {Array.<string>} x */
const b = x => x;

/** @param {Array<string>} x */
const c = x => x;

/** @param {string[]} x */
const d = x => x;

a(['foo', 3]); // OK (we just need an array)
b(['foo', 3]); // ERR: 3 is not a string
c(['foo', 3]); // ERR: 3 is not a string
d(['foo', 3]); // ERR: 3 is not a string
```

So it pretty much seems like that `{Array.<string>}` and `{Array<string>}` are the same thing.

Personally I would favour `{Array<string>}` over `{Array.<string>}`. Why? The dot `.` is also a "namespace" separator:

```js
/** @namespace */
const Burrito = {};

/** @constructor */
Burrito.beef = function () {};

/** @param {Burrito.beef} x */
const a = x => x;

a("foo");
a(new Burrito.beef());
```

The Google Closure compiler will issue a warning about the first call (the second call is fine):

```
JSC_TYPE_MISMATCH: actual parameter 1 of a does not match formal parameter
found   : string
required: (Burrito.beef|null) at line 10 character 2
a("foo");
  ^
```

See this Google Closure Compiler [fiddle](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home#code%3D%252F%252F%2520%253D%253DClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540output_file_name%2520default.js%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540compilation_level%2520ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS%250A%252F%252F%2520%253D%253D%252FClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%250A%252F**%2520%2540namespace%2520*%252F%250Aconst%2520Burrito%2520%253D%2520%257B%257D%253B%250A%250A%252F**%2520%2540constructor%2520*%252F%250ABurrito.beef%2520%253D%2520function%2520()%2520%257B%257D%253B%250A%250A%252F**%2520%2540param%2520%257BBurrito.beef%257D%2520x%2520*%252F%250Aconst%2520a%2520%253D%2520x%2520%253D%253E%2520x%253B%250A%250Aa(%2522foo%2522)%253B%250Aa(new%2520Burrito.beef())%253B%250A).

If `{Array<string>}` and `{Array.<string>}` are genuinely the same thing (and I believe that to be true) then I would favour the former over the latter so as to keep the meaning of the `.` character unambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

As per JSDoc documentation syntax with dot is correct.
https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html

An array of MyClass instances.

```
{Array.<MyClass>}
// or:
{MyClass[]}
```

Comment: Also refer JSDoc namepaths; https://jsdoc.app/about-namepaths.html